# Github API V3 Search Repo issues

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to get 3 repos with highest numbers of stars in given language. I have 3 issues with it:

- search is using legacy pagination style and per_page does not seem to work
- language parameter is also not respected, I get php, java etc
- i'm sorting by start but in result i get detailed repo info with everything 
  but stars count...

```sh
curl "https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/foobar?sort=stars&order=desc&language=VimL&per_page=3"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `per_page` isn't [listed](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) as an accepted parameter. With that in mind, it could be invalidating the rest of your parameters being sent. If removing that does in fact fix the issue, you should [contact](https://github.com/contact) GitHub support directly. If in fact you do this, be sure to include "API" in the topic so it gets routed directly to the API team so you can get your answer faster.

Re:

> i'm sorting by start but in result i get detailed repo info with everything but stars count.

The legacy API (as you already noted this was) returned old style (v2) Repository information. If you want information about the stars you'll have to make a direct call to `/repos/:user/:repo` after you find the repositories you want.

Comment: it turns that it was just a name change and watchers are called stars now. so in v2 api watcher is the number i wanted. no need to make extra api call. you were right about per_page, thanks!